# Rotating and aligning cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet I have created from pulling data from an ini file, and I am looking to align the data better.
For example, here is a sample of my data:
[Sample Data:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a20oU.jpg)

What i am looking to do is create one line for "140DTS" and have a column for Desc, DIMSEATitle, DIMSEPort, and Address.  The last 4 columns are all the same values, so they would remain, but would obviously only need one column for them.

I thought a Pivot table would do it, but its only showing me the Count, not the actual Value.  And Transpose is too much of a manual process (the entire spreadsheet has 1500+ rows).

Any way to speed this up, or do something I'm not sure how to do in Excel?

Comment: I didn't get why is transpose "too much of manual process".  Just make a new sheet, Copy all data of your first sheet have, right click on A1 cell of the new sheet and click transpose. Or, you might see the option of paste special. click in it and you will see the option of transpose

Comment: The problem with Transpose is I only want one instance of the data in column A.  If I select the entire spreadsheet, copy, and Transpose into a new sheet, it creates row 1 of the data I am looking to remove duplicates for. As a workaround, I copied all of Column A, then removed duplicates.  Now I can select the other columns and Transpose, but I can only select the 3 associated lines at a time.